# how to check the expiration date of my token every hour (javascript -react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logout

I need to control every tot time (es. 1h) if my token is expired. if is a make logout.

How can I launch a function that does the check every hour? something that no will stop my work so  not the setTimeout ...

There is a mode to do that? as every hour the system call this function...?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)?

Answer (score 1):

Although the use case is not exactly clear, this sounds like something that `ServiceWorker`s can do. You can read more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/).

> A service worker is a script that your browser runs in the background, separate from a web page, opening the door to features that don't need a web page or user interaction.

**TL;DR**

The idea is that you can have in the browser another "thread" ongoing, regardless of the activity of the webapp/websote which it is bound to. Something like Facebook notifications that appear even when you're not on Facebook.

If you can add more information, I'll be glad to help out and enrich this answer.

Comment: I have my web-app , the web-app still work normally while the user work on it, i want that every tot time es. 1h start one function for control expired date of my token ( the app use OAuth authorisation) and in this function i will control the date and make logout....